# Retrieve all the columns and its data from the Map in one shot

Tags: java, dictionary

**Problem Statement:-**

I have a map named `attributes` which will have `column names` and its `corresponding values` in that Map.

Suppose if I have `col1 to coln` in the `attributes map` and its corresponding values.

Then I will be writing my code like this with all the column names and its values-

```
MutationBatch m = CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getKeyspace().prepareMutationBatch();
 m.withRow(CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getEmp_cf(), userId)
.putColumn("col1", value1, null)
.putColumn("col2", value2, null)
.
.
.
.putColumn("coln", valuen, null)
;
```

Now I need to do the same thing in my below method which will have two parameters-

```
userId and attributes
```

Now I am not sure how to write the above code in such a way so that all the columns and its values are retrieved in one shot.

Below is the method-

```
    public void upsertAttributes(final String userId, final Map<String, String> attributes) {

        MutationBatch m = CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getKeyspace().prepareMutationBatch();

        m.withRow(CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getEmp_cf(), userId)
        .putColumn(attributeName from attributesMap, attributeValue from attributesMap, null)
        .putColumn(attributeName from attributesMap, attributeValue from attributesMap, null)   
        .putColumn(attributeName from attributesMap, attributeValue from attributesMap, null)
        .
        .
        .
        .putColumn(attributeName from attributesMap, attributeValue from attributesMap, null)
;

    }
```

Comment: Why does it need to be "one shot" (I assume you mean one statement(?

Comment: Yeah I guess, you are right. By one shot, I means, I need to retrieve all the column names and column values from the map in one go then by that I can make my above statement I guess. Right? If I can retrieve everything from the map in one go then I can make that statement I guess. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Are you asking us how to loop over the entries of a map?

Comment: I am just asking, how to iterate in such a way such that I can make my above statement from that map. I am confused how should I do that in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood what you want, but it seems you just want to loop over the entries of a map:

```
MutationBatch m = 
    CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getKeyspace().prepareMutationBatch();
ColumnListMutation<String> mutation = 
    m.withRow(CassandraAstyanaxConnection.getInstance().getEmp_cf(), userId);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : attributes.entrySet()) {
    mutation = mutation.putColumn(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks JB. I just tried that. But it is giving me one compilation exception- `The method putColumn(String, String, null) is undefined for the type MutationBatch`. Any idea?

Comment: This is the full signature-  `<String, String> ColumnListMutation<String> com.netflix.astyanax.MutationBatch.withRow(ColumnFamily<String, String> columnFamily, String rowKey)`

Comment: See my edits. I didn't know about the Cassandra API and assumed withRow returned an instance of MutationBatch.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I am not sure how to write the above code in such a way so that
>   all the columns and its values are retrieved in one shot.

You can't.  Instead, you would use a loop like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Row {

    String[] data = new String[10];
    int pos = 0;

    public Row putColumn(String x, String y) {
        data[pos++] = x;
        data[pos++] = y;

        return this;
    }

    public void show() {
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }
    }

}

public class MyProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attributes.put("col1", "val1");
        attributes.put("col2", "val2");
        attributes.put("col3", "val3");
        attributes.put("col4", "val4");

        upsertAttributes(attributes);
    }

    public static void upsertAttributes(final Map<String, String> attributes) {
        Row r = new Row();
        Iterator<String> keyIterator = attributes.keySet().iterator();

        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = keyIterator.next();
            String val = attributes.get(key);
            r.putColumn(key, val);
        }

        r.show();
    }

}

--output:--
col4
val4
col1
val1
col3
val3
col2
val2
null
null
```

Imagine if your map had 10,000,000 entries.  Are you really going to print out all the values in the map, and then look at the keys and values and write out 10,000,000 lines of code like this:

```
.putColumn('a key I see', 'its value', null)
.putColumn('another key I see', 'its value', null)
...
...
...
.putcolumn('key10,000,000', 'val10,000,000', null)
```